# how to retrieve deleted folder from linux mint server

Tags: linux-mint, user-folders

A few students in our IT class delete their personal folders from our Linux mint student server occasionally.  Is there any way of retrieving deleted file folders?  We run a network with a windows 7 main server and a Linux mint server for student folders. We would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Restore from your backups. You are backing up your servers, right? If not, why not?

Comment: Oh dear. https://www.hadleighfarm.org.uk/training-opportunities/hadleigh-training-centre > "An error occurred during a connection to www.hadleighfarm.org.uk. Peer's Certificate has been revoked. (Error code: sec_error_revoked_certificate) "

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but there are many factors that will limit what you can do including filesystem type, time of deletion, etc.

I've used [PhotoRec](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) to recover files on a server in the past with success. It is a tool created to recover photos that were accidently deleted but it also works for other files.

Another method is to use `debugfs`. [Linux debugfs Hack: Undelete Files](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-ext3-ext4-deleted-files-recovery-howto.html)

EX:

```
$ debugfs -w /dev/mapper/mydisk-root
$ debugfs: lsdel
```

Sample output:

```
    Inode  Owner  Mode    Size    Blocks   Time deleted
    23601299      0 120777      3    1/   1 Tue Mar 13 16:17:30 2012
    7536655      0 120777      3    1/   1 Tue May  1 06:21:22 2012
    2 deleted inodes found.
```

Run the command in debugfs:

```
    debugfs: logdump -i <7536655>
```

Determine inodes:

```
    ...
    ...
    ....
    output truncated
        Fast_link_dest: bin
        Blocks:  (0+1): 7235938
      FS block 7536642 logged at sequence 38402086, journal block 26711
        (inode block for inode 7536655):
        Inode: 7536655   Type: symlink        Mode:  0777   Flags: 0x0   Generation: 3532221116
        User:     0   Group:     0   Size: 3
        File ACL: 0    Directory ACL: 0
        Links: 0   Blockcount: 0
        Fragment:  Address: 0    Number: 0    Size: 0
        ctime: 0x4f9fc732 -- Tue May  1 06:21:22 2012
        atime: 0x4f9fc730 -- Tue May  1 06:21:20 2012
        mtime: 0x4f9fc72f -- Tue May  1 06:21:19 2012
        dtime: 0x4f9fc732 -- Tue May  1 06:21:22 2012
        Fast_link_dest: bin
        Blocks:  (0+1): 7235938
    No magic number at block 28053: end of journal.
```

Run `dd` with inode info from block:

```
    # dd if=/dev/mapper/mydisk-root of=recovered.file.001 bs=4096 count=1 skip=7235938
    # file recovered.file.001
    file: ASCII text, with very long lines
```

Files been recovered to `recovered.file.001`.